# Haskell Debugging

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

How can I print a list or something in haskell at every call for example :

```
funct a list = funct (a + 1) (a : list) 
               print list here ??????? but how ?
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For debugging, there's

```
import Debug.Trace

funct :: Integer -> [Integer] -> Bool 
funct a list = trace (show list) $ funct (a + 1) (a : list)
```

where `trace :: String -> a -> a`. It uses `unsafePerformIO` under the hood, so it's evil and *only* for debugging.

Be aware that due to lazy evaluation, the debugging output may appear in surprising order and interleaved with the output the program would normally generate.

With

```
module TraceIt where

import Debug.Trace

funct :: Integer -> [Integer] -> Bool
funct 10 list = null list
funct a list = trace (show list) $ funct (a + 1) (a : list)
```

I get

```
*TraceIt> funct 1 []
[]
[1]
[2,1]
[3,2,1]
[4,3,2,1]
[5,4,3,2,1]
[6,5,4,3,2,1]
[7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
[8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
False
```

as expected.

Comment: but it works only for the last call, if I go recursively and it enters in a guard it shows only the last call how can I make to show all calls ???

Comment: That would be very surprising. Unless your tracing string is constant and you compile with optimisations, then that is normal. For the above, I get tracing output in every call.

Comment: Ah thanks, forgot about that. It's too new to have reached my long-term memory.

Answer (score 1):

Same as Daniel Fisher suggested, but with `unsafePerformIO` only.

```
> import System.IO.Unsafe
> let funct a list = unsafePerformIO $ do { print list; return $ funct (a + 1) (a : list) }
```

Take a look at the [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546592/how-to-debug-haskell-with-printfs) describes what is really going on when you use `unsafePerformIO`.